# How should I go about asking about translating a mathematical term from one language to another?

Tags: discussion, languages

Most of mathematical texts I read are in English, which is not my native language. When I learn a new concept, I often don't know how to translate it to Polish. Sometimes, although rarely, it's the other way around. Can I ask here what a translation of a term is? If so, how should I do this? I think a question entitled "How do you say *group-bound semigroup* in Polish" would be definitely much too specific.

I thought it could be possible to try to create some CW questions like "Dictionary of Measure Theory Terms" or "Dictionary of Ring Theory", which people could edit to add terms in different languages (with usage notes if necessary). They could be split into parts when they get too large.

Do you think it's a good idea? If not, how would you go about it?

**EDIT.** I just thought that if we created such "questions", the "answers" could be used to ask actual questions about some particular terms.

Comment: Since we recently had two questions related to this topic, I thought that creating [meta-tag:languages] might be a good idea - meta.SO has such [tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/languages).

Comment: I tried to search whether we already have some posts which are of this type or at least related. I found these:
[What resources are there for learning Russian math terminology?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46408/) and
[When does variété mean manifold?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40140/).

Comment: I have to ask, how do you call Polish groups/spaces/etc. in Polish? :-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila The same as in English, "grupy/przestrzenie polskie". :-)

Comment: Another question related to translating mathematical term: [Translation from French](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59801/translation-from-french).

Comment: @ymar You've suggested that we build some kind of collaboratively edited dictionary for mathematics here. Perhaps before doing so, we could ask whether there already are some dictionaries which can be edited by users and which are (preferably) specialized on science. I think this would be an appropriate question to ask on the main site. (Maybe even something which is not devoted exclusively to science topics would be reasonable.)

Comment: I don't think developing math dictionaries here would be a good idea, since to some extent I think it would be reinventing the wheel as far as the major mathematical languages are concerned. I agree with Martin that it would be better to list scientific (if not specifically mathematical) dictionaries that are already published or available online. Personally I find it pretty convenient to look up the English wikipedia page on a topic and then just scroll the left margin to another foreign language to find out the name for that term in that language, but there is not always such a page.

Comment: @KCd That's the problem. I also use the Wikipedia option quite a lot but it often doesn't work. I haven't found anything close to complete on the web as English-Polish translation goes. I rarely have to look up terms in other languages, but when I do, I often have trouble too.

Comment: @MartinSleziak I see that you have asked this question. I'll add a [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164553/dictionaries-and-resources-for-translation-of-mathematical-terminology).